# StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthGuardSuperAdmin]: NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthGuardSuperAdmin

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from './../login/login.service';
import { UserService } from './../user/user.service';

@Injectable()


export class AuthGuardSuperAdmin implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private userService: UserService){ }
    loggedIn; userData; id;

    getData(){
        this.id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.userService.userSelectOne(this.id).subscribe(data =>{
            this.userData = data;
        });
    }

    canActivate(){
        if(this.loginService.loggedIn()){
            if(this.userData[0]['userStatus']){
                return true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/product']);
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData();
        this.canActivate();
    }
}
```

I want to use UserService to identify the details of the user, the code below represents the canActivate in angular routing. But some error occurs and I can't figure it why? I want to restrict a user accessing a route depending on his/her status. admin; or superAdmin

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'user', 
    component: UserComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardSuperAdmin] 
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **`AuthGuardSuperAdmin`** inside the providers of **`app.module.ts`**

```
 providers: [AuthGuardSuperAdmin ]
```

Comment: I want to access the UserService inside the AuthGuardSuperAdmin, but there is no providers array, only injectables()

Comment: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OrderComponent -> UserService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OrderComponent -> UserService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for UserService

Comment: Did you add `UserService` to module providers in `app.module.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 6 just change this:

```
@Injectable()
```

to:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```

No other changes needed. This will inject the service on demand without the need to add it to a providers array.